# Regular expression match / split

Tags: python, regex

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to use regular expressions in python. Ultimately I am trying to do what sscanf does for me in C.

I am trying to match given strings that look like so:

`12345_arbitrarystring_2020_05_20_10_10_10.dat`

I (seem) to be able to validate this format by calling match on the following regular expression

`regex = re.compile('[0-9]{5}_.+_[0-9]{4}([-_])[0-9]{2}([-_])[0-9]{2}([-_])[0-9]{2}([:_])[0-9]{2}([:_])[0-9]{2}\\.dat')`

(Note that I do allow for a few other separators then just '_')

I would like to split the given string on these separators so I do:

```
regex = re.compile('[_\\-:.]+')
parts = regex.split(given_string)
```

This is all fine .. the problem is that I would like my 'arbitrarystring' part to include '-' and '_' and the last split currently, well, splits them.

Other than manually cutting the timestamp and the first 5 digits off that given string, what can I do to get that arbitrarystring part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to get the arbitrarystring part and omit the other capturing groups.

You could for example use a character class to match 1+ word characters or a hyphen using `[\w-]+`

If you still want to use split, you could add capturing groups for the first and the second part, and split only those groups.

```
^[0-9]{5}_([\w-]+)_[0-9]{4}[-_][0-9]{2}[-_][0-9]{2}[-_][0-9]{2}[:_][0-9]{2}[:_][0-9]{2}\.dat$
          ^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR0SLj/1)

Comment: Same concept. Nice as usuall =)

Comment: @JvdV If the OP wants a broader match than only word chars or a hyphen, then your pattern would be better approach using the non greedy dot.

Comment: Thanks, and I didn't know regex101 either!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible to cut down your regex to validate the whole pattern to:

```
^\d{5}_(.+?)_\d{4}[-_](?:\d{2}[-_]){2}(?:\d{2}[:_]){2}\d{2}\.dat$
```

Refer to group 1 for your arbitrary string.

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJGo4v/4/)

---

*Quick reminder:* You didn't seem to have used raw strings, but instead escaping with a double backslash. Python has [raw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/9758194) strings which makes you don't have to escape backslashes nomore.